# C struct compilation fails

Tags: c, struct, enums, microchip

I'm working on a driver for the **Microchip Harmony Framework**. It looks like a Linux driver. I've got a `struct` (`NRF24L01_MainStateInfo`) that stores all the state needed  by the driver, it's just a "collection" made of `enum`s. It's been like **2** days that I'm struggling to this:

> ../../../../framework/driver/nrf24l01/src/states/initialization_state/../../../drv_nrf24l01.h:51:2: error: unknown type name 'NRF24L01_MainStateInfo''

The `struct` that has a member of that type (and where the error points) is the following one:

```
#ifndef __DRV_NRF24L01_H__
#define __DRV_NRF24L01_H__

// Framework include
//...
// Project specific include
#include "src/memory_map.h"
#include "src/nrf_definitions.h"
#include "src/states/drv_nrf24l01_main_state.h" // NRF24L01_MainStateInfo defined here
#include "src/bus/drv_nrf24l01_bus.h"
//...
typedef struct _nrf24l01_driver_info {
    // Driver in use? (already configured)
    bool inUse;
    // Driver's mutex
    OSAL_MUTEX_HANDLE_TYPE drvMutex;
    // Driver configuration
    NRF24L01_ConfigData config;
    // Client count. Useless since there is a mapping 1:1 between driver and client
    uint8_t clientCnt;
    // Driver system status (returned by status)
    SYS_STATUS status;
    // FSM state
    NRF24L01_MainStateInfo state; // <-- This member generate the error

    // Bus information
    NRF24L01_BusVTable vTable;
    void *busInfo;

} NRF24L01_DriverInfo;

//...

#endif
```

The structure `NRF24L01_MainStateInfo` is declared in `src/states/drv_nrf24l01_main_state.h` as follow:

```
#ifndef __DRV__NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_H__
#define __DRV__NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_H__

//#include "../../drv_nrf24l01.h"
#include "initialization_state/drv_nrf24l01_init_state.h"

struct _nrf24l01_driver_info;

/*
  Main driver state. These are the state that the developer will see.
*/
typedef enum {
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0,
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_INITIALIZATION,
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_RUNNING,
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_CLOSING,
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_CLOSED
} NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE;

typedef struct _nrf24l01_mainstate_info {
  NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE mainState;
  NRF24L01_INIT_STATE initState;
} NRF24L01_MainStateInfo;

int32_t DRV_nRF24L01_MainStateTask(struct _nrf24l01_driver_info *pDrv);

#endif /* end of include guard: __DRV__NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_H__ */
```

Now I can't figure why this error came up.

The directory tree is the following:

```
nrf24l01 .
│   drv_nrf24l01.h
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│
├───config
│       .gitignore
│       drv_nrf.hconfig
│       drv_nrf24l01.hconfig
│       drv_nrf24l01_idx.ftl
│
├───src
│   │   drv_nrf24l01.c
│   │   memory_map.h
│   │   nrf_definitions.h
│   │
│   ├───bus
│   │   │   drv_nrf24l01_bus.h
│   │   │
│   │   └───spi
│   │           drv_nrf24l01_spi.c
│   │           drv_nrf24l01_spi.h
│   │
│   ├───internal
│   │       drv_nrf_internal.c
│   │       drv_nrf_internal.h
│   │
│   └───states
│       │   drv_nrf24l01_main_state.c
│       │   drv_nrf24l01_main_state.h
│       │
│       ├───closing_state
│       ├───initialization_state
│       │       drv_nrf24l01_init_state.c
│       │       drv_nrf24l01_init_state.h
│       │
│       └───running_state
└───templates
        system_config.h.ftl
        system_definitions.h.INC.ftl
        system_definitions.h.OBJ.ftl
        system_init.c.DRV.ftl
        system_init.c.INIT.ftl
        system_interrupt.c.ftl
        system_tasks.c.ftl
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

The compiler is the **xc32-gcc** and the uC is a **PIC32MX110F016B**.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problems, but it is worth noting that symbols starting with two underscores or with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved in C, and defining them yourself is results in undefined behavior.

Comment: did you look for the undefined enum in the include files?

Comment: Can you make sure you don't have an errant header preprocessor guard `__DRV__NRF24L01_MAIN_STATE_H__` in another file that is preventing `src/states/drv_nrf24l01_main_state.h` from being fully included?

Comment: @Christian Gibbons All my guards are now `DRV_NRF24L01_xxxx_H` but the problem is still there

Comment: @MFisherKDX just check, only 2 matches (3 with a comment on `#endif`)

Comment: @Jay i don't have undefined enums

Comment: 1) After `typedef struct _nrf24l01_mainstate_info { ...} NRF24L01_MainStateInfo;`, add `#error stop` to validate expected code is compiling to that `typedef`. 2) Make names shorter.

Comment: @chux 1) the compilation stops at `#error ...` as expected 2) truncated to less than 10 chars, nothing changes

Comment: Hmmm UNless `NRF24L01_MainStateInfo` is redefined later - you have a poser.  Suggest keep simplifying the code.  Good luck.

Comment: Where and how is NRF24L01_INIT_STATE defined?

Comment: IMO over complicated structure for this simple device. you could cover in this structure complicated uC

Comment: @MiCo True, `NRF24L01_INIT_STATE` definition is missing.

Comment: Your error says a camel cased version is not defined but your .h file defines it in all lower case: "typedef struct _nrf24l01_mainstate_info."

Comment: @MiCo @Jay it is defined in `initialization_state/drv_nrf24l01_init_state.h`

Comment: @Jay the whole declaration is `typedef struct _nrf24l01_mainstate_info { ...} NRF24L01_MainStateInfo;` so I can use both `struct _nrf24l01_mainstate_info` or `NRF24L01_MainStateInfo`

Comment: @P__J__ maybe it's a bit complicated yet, a refactoring is needed, but since this is a driver that will be managed by the OS I'm forced to manage a lot of stuff

Comment: File structure too complicated which is usually a sign of the bad design. BTW what OS on uC with 32k of FLASH

Comment: @P__J__ I'm using the one that comes with [Microchip Harmony framework](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-harmony), it's an abstraction layer (OSAL) that's based on a preemptive scheduler, so I can have different  applications running "simultaneously"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular header dependency, which is bad design and almost always leads to failures. The problem is complicated by an overly-complicated naming strategy which makes the code really difficult to read.

Here's the basic problem, using significantly simplified names:

#### File driver.h

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

#include "state.h"

/* See answer text for an explanation of this declaration style. */
typedef struct Driver Driver;
struct Driver {
  // ...
  State state;
  // ...
};

#endif
```

#### File state.h

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

// Needed because the Driver type is used in a prototype
#include "driver.h"

typedef struct State State;
struct State {
  // ...
};

// Attempt to fix circular dependency with a redundant declaration.
typedef struct Driver Driver;
int32_t stateTask(Driver* driver);
#endif
```

So these two headers include each other. The header guards will keep them from being included twice, but they won't guarantee that the declarations are read in the correct order. What will happen depends on which order you `#include` the two headers:

- If you first `#include "driver.h"`, it will set its header guard and immediately `#include "state.h"`. It hasn't been included before, so the header guard isn't set and the compiler starts processing it. It immediately hits `#include driver.h"`, but that header guard is now set, even though the header hasn't really yet been processed, so circular inclusion is avoided. Eventually reaches the prototype which references the type `Driver`, which hasn't been defined yet.

  I assume you already hit this problem because of the redundant `struct` declarations in `state.h`. After inserting these declarations, you could have removed the `#include "driver.h"` but perhaps you had some other need for it.
- On the other hand, if you first `#include "state.h"`, the compiler sees that its header guard hasn't been set, sets the header guard, and proceeds with the header. It immediately sees `#include "driver.h"`; that header guard has not yet been set, so it sets that header guard and proceeds with that header. Now when it hits the `#include "state.h"` in the `driver.h` header, it does nothing because the header guard has now been set.

  Unfortunately, that `#include` is really necessary. Compilation fails when an attempt is made to define a member of type `State`, which has not yet been defined. In this case, you're actually including an entire `State` object, not just using a pointer, so you can't get away with just forward declaring the `struct` tab.

In short, things will work OK with one header include order, but fail with a different one. Unfortunately, it's very hard to predict the order in which headers will be included in a complex project, because header includes are not always visible. They may occur inside other headers which are being included. This can lead to headers being included in the "wrong" order.

In general, it is not a good idea to write headers which must be `#include`d in a particular order. It almost always ends in this kind of problem.

When you have several inter-related types all being used by the same small component, you are better off putting all of them into a single header. You will still need to sort the order out correctly, but at least they are all in one place. In that single header file, it may be necessary to forward-declare structures in order to allow pointers to them from other structures. Putting the type definitions ahead of the prototypes reduces the need to forward-declare for prototype references.

If you have a lot of types, you could put all of their declarations in a single internal `project/types.h` header. Then you can arrange the prototypes in whatever complicated file organisation you fancy. This is a pretty common paradigm. For external prototype headers -- that is, headers which declare functions intended to be globally visible -- you might be able to reduce clutter by just forward declaring the structs being used by the prototypes. Assuming the prototype only uses a pointer to the struct, which is certainly the most common, there is no need to make the definition of the struct visible.

***Warning:*** Opinionated style recommendations follow. If you don't like that sort of thing, you can stop reading here.

Once you have your headers sorted out, assuming they are only being used internally, you can simplify things for yourself and your readers by dropping unnecessary prefixes from internal structure and enum names. Typedefs, structure and union tags, and enums do not have linkage; they cannot leak into another separately compiled translation unit. So there is no need to make them globally unique if they are not intended for global use.

Regardless of what you might see in other people's code, there is absolutely no need to make typedef names different from struct tags, even if you someday intend to compile with C++. In C, the names are in two completely separate namespaces; a struct tag is only recognised as such when preceded with the token `struct`. So

```
typedef struct MyStructure MyStructure;
```

is absolutely valid. In fact, it is valid even if `struct MyStructure` has not yet been fleshed out, making it convenient for structure types which include pointers to the same type.

I tend to use the style shown in the code snippets above, always putting the `typedef` before the struct definition. I find that more readable than having the typedef name way down at the end of the struct definition, even if in my style the names are always the same. Also, the forward `typedef`s can simply be copied to headers which need them. C does not complain if you `typedef` the same name to the same type more than once, so this is totally safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this evening I will look closely and refactor a bit following your advices! I'll let you know ;)

Comment: Ok, took me a while but I did some test and yes, that's it @rici ! Anyway, I decided to re-write some parts of the driver and simplified it as much as I can. Thanks again for the precious advices!